# Kafka: Why would a message show up duplicated when consuming from my topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

I have a lambda which gets triggered as a result of S3 bucket inputs, reads the contents of the file from the bucket and produces these contents as a message to my Kafka topic

I use Amazon MSK as a broker.

I tested what all had been sent to my topic, and 1 single file input (containing one simple line "hello"). And noticed that it was duplicated 3 times.

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server {bootstrap_server} --consumer.config -- client.properties --topic MyTopic --from-beginning
```

I got:

```
hello
hello
hello
```

I had just freshly made this topic, and had not attempted to input this file before.

When I re-ran the `./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server {bootstrap_server} --consumer.config -- client.properties --topic MyTopic --from-beginning` command, the repeated "hello" was replaced with a single "hello" and 2 blank lines.

What could have happened here?

Apologies that this is very anecdotal. I've struggled to replicate this.